# Django DetailView dynamic model

Tags: python, django, django-models, view

I'm trying to create one view for several Models for a django app. The app basically is an admin backend with some customized functions.

In the update view of each item, I think is better to have only one DetailView defined and dynamically getting the model name.

1) Is it a correct approach or is better one DetailView for each model?

2) Is it possible? If so, how can it be done?

**views.py**

```
class EquipoUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = DYNAMIC_MODEL
    fields = ['codigo', 'equipo', 'nombre', 'fabricante', 'modelo', 'fecha_alta', 'fecha_baja', 'descripcion','datos_contacto']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('listados-mantenimiento', kwargs={'model_type': 'componentes'})
    template_name = 'manager/mto/mto_update.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^mantenimiento/(?P<model_type>\w{0,50})/update/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.EquipoUpdate.as_view()),
```

the `DYNAMIC_MODEL` is the variable I want to get from urls.py `model_type`

My first approach was to use `def get_context_data`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    modelo = self.kwargs['model_type']
    context = super(MtoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if (modelo == 'equipos'):
        context['listado'] = Equipo.objects.all()
    elif (modelo == 'componentes'):
        context['listado'] = Componente.objects.all()
    ...
```

but I'm afraid a big database would lead to performance isues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `get_queryset()` method to return the appropriate model's queryset after getting the model from `model_kwarg`.

To get the model from the `model_type` kwarg, you can create a `MODEL_TYPE_KWARGS_TO_MODEL_MAPPING` dictionary. It will return the model by performing lookup on it with `model_type` kwarg as key. Ofcourse, you will have to add error handling for invalid `model_type` cases.

You can do something like:

```
class DynamicModelUpdate(UpdateView):

    def get_queryset(self):
         model = MODEL_TYPE_KWARGS_TO_MODEL_MAPPING[self.kwargs['model_type']]
         return model.objects.all()
```